# Why has the Work Management SA been removed from Sharepoint 2016

Tags: task-list, 2016, mytask

Does anyone know why the Work Management Service Application was removed from Sharepoint 2016? Something to do with an overall goal of hybrid-everything in Sharepoint 2016 (wrt Sharepoint Online)?

It was very useful for aggregating tasks on the users' mysites - although it is possible to roll one's own using search, I think this is a very strange move by MS

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft first removed this feature in Office 365. This has now been [adopted to SharePoint 2016 OnPrem](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt346112(v=office.16).aspx#Anchor_3).

Microsoft never gave us a reason for this decision. [This Blog-Post](https://absolute-sharepoint.com/2014/09/microsoft-killing-features-office-365-sharepoint-online.html) has an overview and also an interesting discussion in the comments.